# Visual Basic Randomizing numbers and setting them to a song

Tags: vb.net

Can someone help me with a program in visual basic. I need a random number generator to choose random numbers and play certain songs based on those numbers. I cant remember how to set a number to each song. I know i need some kind of if then statement. It will generate the random songs when a button is clicked. Does anyone know how to do this? I need the whole code including the dim 1 as integer. This is what i have so far, I know it is completely wrong. Thanks in advance

```
Public Class NameTheArtist

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim number As Integer
        Dim rndnumber As Random
        rndnumber = New Random
        number = rndnumber.Next(1, 10)


        Dim 1  As Integer
        Dim 2 As Integer
        Dim 3 As Integer
        Dim 4 As Integer
        Dim 6 As Integer
        Dim 7 As Integer
        Dim 8 As Integer
        Dim 9 As Integer
        Dim 10 As Integer
        Dim 5 As Integer 

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



    Public Function GetRandom(ByVal Min As Integer, ByVal Max As Integer) As Integer
        Dim Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()
        Return Generator.Next(1, 10)
    End Function

    Public Function Play(ByVal Num As Integer)
        If num = 1 Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Black_Widow, AudioPlayMode.Background)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
            Return True
        ElseIf num = 2 Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.music2, AudioPlayMode.Background)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
            Return True
        End If
        If number = 1 Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Black_Widow, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.All_about_that_bass, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Trumpets, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Love_story, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        Return False
    End Function
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Asking StackOverflow to write the app for you is not the way to go. If you have specific questions about how to use the language you can ask them here. As this stands, it's not even clear what you are asking for.

Comment: i feel like he tries to add a number as tag to his songs and then play the song belonging to the randomly generated number. seems like legit question to me. althought this try is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are looking for something like this:

```
Public Function Play(ByVal Num As Integer) as Boolean
Select Case num
Case 1
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Black_Widow, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Return True    
Case 2
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.music2, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Return True  
Case 3
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.whatever, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Return True
Case n
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.song_n, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Return True
End Select 
Return False
End Function
```

create a case for every number/song you got. i dont see what that integers you have declared are for. you might remove these to clean your code.